# SnakeYAML: How do I load a yaml with Set using TypeDescription?

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I'm using a Set in my YAML similar to this:

```
# Explicitly typed set.
baseball players: !!set
  ? Mark McGwire
  ? Sammy Sosa
  ? Ken Griffey
# Flow style
baseball teams: !!set { Boston Red Sox, Detroit Tigers, New York Yankees }
```

How do I explicitly set the type to Set while registering my Constructor?

TypeDescription only lets me to either register a List or a Map as per docs:
http://javadox.com/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/org/yaml/snakeyaml/TypeDescription.html

```
 void   putListPropertyType(String property, Class<? extends Object> type)
          Specify that the property is a type-safe List.
 void   putMapPropertyType(String property, Class<? extends Object> key, Class<? extends Object> value)
          Specify that the property is a type-safe Map.
```

I ended up converting my Sets to Lists due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out eventually. YAML Sets are Maps with null values. So I ended up defining my data model to have a Set member, and then I used putMapPropertyType API to register the binding.

```
Class Config {
   Set<String> players;
}


// in the YAML parsing code block :
typeDef.putMapPropertyType("players", String.class, Object.class /* Value type doesnt matter */ );
```

Hope this helps.